# Not being able to look sideways in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, quaternions

I want to make a fps game. To create first person viewer I followed this tutorial [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc)

I followed everything that he told to do and I could successfully look up or down but could not look sideways.

Here`s the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mousesenitivevity = 100f;
    public Transform player_eyes;

    float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mousesenitivevity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mousesenitivevity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        player_eyes.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }
}
```

I really do not know where the error is occurring but here are a few things I noticed:

If you comment out the line `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);` then the player can look sideways but not up and down and if you uncomment it the player can look up and down but not sideways.

Here is the unity editor screenshots for more details:
[Editor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdsfj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I put the script on the player instead of the camera by mistake.